# Possible outcome

Tags: probability-theory

A bag containing 6 white & 6 black socks . A sock is drawn from the bag, and it's color recorded, & put back in the bag. This is done 3 times.

Part A : show all possible outcomes. Let w stand for white & b for black.

Part B : based on answer to part A, how many outcomes contain two or more white socks ?

Part C: if 40 students did this, based on answer to Part B, How many students would you expect to get 2 or more white socks ?

Comment: Do you expect us to do your homework for you? What part of the problem you don't understand? What are your thougts about the problem/what have you tried?

Comment: Thank you ! I was trying to understand this. I'm a grandmother trying to understand in order to try and help her grandson who has ADD & is on the autistic spectrum. I do not understand " all possible outcomes " how many possible outcomes should there be ?? How do you get that number? What I've tried to do is learn along with him.

Answer (score 1):

Part A:

www /
wwb /
wbw /
wbb /
bww /
bwb /
bbw /
bbb

So there is 8 possible outcomes.
Formally, you have two options when taking from the bag every time. Since you did it 3 times, you have $2 \times 2 \times 2 = 8$ possible outcomes.

Part B:

$\textbf{www}$ /
$\textbf{wwb}$ /
$\textbf{wbw}$ /
wbb /
$\textbf{bww}$ /
bwb /
bbw /
bbb

So, 4 from 8 possible outcomes contains two or more white socks, i.e., 1/2 of all.

Part C:

Let $P(s_i)$ be the probability of student $s_i$ getting 2 or more white socks, and S be the set of all 40 students. In part B we saw that P(s_i) is 1/2, so the answer is the $\sum_{s_i \in S}P(s_i) = 40 \times 1/2 = 20$

Done. But next time try to explain what were your troubles, and don't just paste your homework.